# Redirect whole script output to file and show in console at the same time

Tags: windows, powershell, server

when I run this script it ask me to fill variables $ComputerName and $OutputFilePath which is path where I want to store whole script output in .txt or .CSV. I wrapped whole script in `$(*script*)*>&1 > $OutputFilePath`. It saving output succesfully to specified path but it didnt print output to console.

How I can save whole output to file and print to console at the same time?

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$OutputFilePath 
)#end param

$(
# All Installed Windows features
Write-Output "===================================================================================================="

Write-Output "ALL INSTALLED WINDOWS FEATURES:" 
Write-Verbose -Message "Searching installed features..." -Verbose
$obj=Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.Installed} | Select-Object Name, InstallState | Format-Table -AutoSize
Write-Output $obj 

Write-Output "===================================================================================================="
)*>&1 > $OutputFilePath
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Start-Transcript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript) is likely what you are looking for. Once invoked it runs in the background and writes your console input and output to a text file - your console functions as normal during this.

It's used like this:

```
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\transcripts\transcript.txt"
#yourcode here
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: It gives me this error: "Stop-Transcript : This host does not support transcription." and I need this to be executed on powershell version min. V2 to newest one.

Comment: You are running it in the Console and not the ISE? Transcription only works in the ISE with PS v5 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with tee-object (which is designed for this exact purpose and supported in v2 also),like this :

```
"testing" *>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath .\OutputFile.txt
```

Comment: when I try task.ps1 *>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath $OutputFilePath it gives me error: "The term 'task.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Comment: @user1994521 can you try with script fullpath like this : D:\logmod.ps1 *>1 | Tee-Object -FilePath test.txt

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a custom 'Write-Terminal' function that outputs to console and appends to a log file at the same time (using a WriteLog function). It also enables you to change the console colour depending on the type of message.

```
Function Write-Terminal
{
<#
.SYNOPSIS
            Write output to the screen
.DESCRIPTION
            <Description of function>
.PARAMETER
            <Input params and descriptions>
.RETURNS
            <What the function returns>
.EXAMPLE
            <Function example>
#>
    Param
    (
        [string]$strOut,
        [string]$strType
    )  

    switch -wildcard ($strOut)
    {
        "ERR:*"     { write-host $strOut -ForegroundColor RED -BackgroundColor BLACK }
        "WARN:*"    { write-host $strOut -ForegroundColor CYAN -BackgroundColor BLACK }
        "WARNING:*" { write-host $strOut -ForegroundColor CYAN -BackgroundColor BLACK }
        "INFO:*"    { write-host $strOut -ForegroundColor YELLOW -BackgroundColor BLACK }
        "DEBUG:*"   { write-host $strOut -ForegroundColor DARKGREEN -BackgroundColor BLACK }
        "OTH:*"     { write-host $strOut -ForegroundColor MAGENTA -BackgroundColor BLACK }  
        default     { write-host $strOut }      
    }
    WriteLog $strOut
} #END Write-Terminal

Function WriteLog
{
<#
.SYNOPSIS
            Write output to a log file
.DESCRIPTION
            <Description of function>
.PARAMETER
            <Input params and descriptions>
.RETURNS
            <What the function returns>
.EXAMPLE
            <Function example>
#>
    Param
    (
        [string]$strOut,
        [bool]$blnNoDate
    )    
    $strDateTime = get-date -uFormat "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"
    If (-not ($blnNoDate)) 
    {
        $strOutPut = ($strDateTime+ ": " + $strOut)
    } 
    else 
    {
        $strOutPut = $strOut
    }
    "$strOutPut" | out-file -filepath "path/to/logfile" -append
} #END WriteLog
```

So in my script everytime I wanted to write to the console and a log file I would use something like:

```
Write-Terminal "Some message"
```

Or if I want an error message to be shown in the console in RED text I would use:

```
Write-Terminal "ERR: Some message"
```

See below for an expanded example of this in a generic script 'template' I use for all my PS scripts these days (compiled from various sources on the web):

https://github.com/Asnivor/PowerShellScriptTemplate

It also allows you to automatically log errors at the same time using the existing framework.

hth.